# in VIM using F5 how to add a placeholder on top

Tags: vim, code-snippets

I have an environment for Theorem (aliased to "thm")
When in VIM editor I write

"thm" followed by "F5"  I get:

```
\begin{thm}

\end{thm}<++>
```

Can I edit the macro so that I get instead:

```
\begin{thm}<++>

\end{thm}<++>
```

It is the case in many theorems where we want to add the name of the theorem.
For example: Roll's theorem....

with the cursor at the beggining?

Comment: I guess you need a plugin of snippet: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips

Answer (score 2):

See the snippet plugin for vim: [ultisnip](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)

Then you can create your own snippet in `tex.snippet`

```
snippet thm "theorem" b
\begin{thm}{${1:name}}
$2
\end{thm}
endsnippet
```

In your tex file, type `thm` at the beginning of the line (`b` set the snippet only triggered at the beginning of the line), and then type the trigger key such as `CTRL-J` or `<tab>`.

```
thm
```

will expand to

```
\begin{thm}{name}

\end{thm}
```

where name is highlighted and selected to be the default value if you do not change it. Type `mytheorem` and then the trigger key, the cursor will then jump to where `$2` is located, so you get

```
\begin{thm}{mytheorem}
| % the cursor
\end{thm}
```

There are also many fancy examples in the documentation of ultisnip to help you to customize your own snippets.

Comment: "snip" is indeed a great tool. This does not answer my  question with <F5> but certainly shows how to go around it. I might migrate to snip from latex-suite but I want to stay within the latex-suite a bit longer.

Comment: @HermanJaramillo Just have a try and take your own suitable way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.
In the "envmacros.vim" file (under ~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite) I defined:

```
let g:Tex_Env_thm = "\\begin{thm}[<++>]\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{thm}<++>"
```

then, when I type 
thm
and push < F5> I get:

```
\begin{thm}[]
    <++>
\end{thm}<++>
```

The cursor located inside the square brackets [].  If I do not want to name the theorem, I move with ctrl-j  to the inside, and another ctrl-j to exit